# Exact proportions of sugar to water in sorbet

Tags: sugar, syrup, sorbet

I am planning to make a sorbet from a cordial which I'm going to make (essentially a flavoured syrup). What proportion of sugar to water to I need to create a smooth, small-crystalled sorbet? Please take in mind I do not own or intend in buying a 'Baum meter' or many other kitchen gadgets although I do own a thermometer. The cordial does contain acid if that should change things.

Comment: It pretty much entirely depends on how much sugar there already is in the cordial. (And how much other flavor - if it's strong, you'll dilute it with sugar water, and if it's weak, you'll use more of the cordial.)

Comment: @Jefromi apologies, I'm going to make the cordial, I should have made clear... Will change the question

Comment: Okay, so... what are your starting ingredients besides sugar and water? Since you're making it all yourself, how is this different from just looking for a recipe using fruit juice of the given type? (And do you not have fresh fruit to start from?) Fruits have different amounts of sugar, so if you're trying to just measure quantities, no one can really hope to give you a good answer without knowing more.

Comment: Also... are you planning to make a cordial by reducing/concentrating fruit juice, then add water back into it to make sorbet?

Comment: Gosh! I have been vague haven't I! It's going to be made from blossom like elderflower cordial! Sorry

Comment: So if I understood right, there's not going to be any sugar in this except for what you add yourself. If that's the case, you might want to edit your question one more time. If not, my answer needs amending.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a recipe for a sorbet without any fruit contributing sugar, but I do have something very close: the lemon sorbet from The Perfect Scoop. It uses a cup of lemon juice, which contains only [6 g of sugar](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1938/2), along with 2.5 cups of water and 1 cup of sugar.

So 3.5 cups (828 mL) of water with 1 cup (200 g) of sugar should be good, or a ratio of 4:1 by weight.